403 Forbidden Error When Using CEO's APS Web App Credentials to Load Autodesk Forge Models
I developed a web application for my company that loads translated Autodesk Forge models by retrieving an access token from the backend. We have an Autodesk ACC Build subscription, where our source design models are uploaded and translated within the ACC Build project's models folder.
I was using my APS web app with its Client_ID and client_secret credentials in the backend token server to obtain an access token for loading these translated models. This setup worked fine until I shared the Build project with the company CEO's ACC account. The CEO created an APS web app, and when I used his APS web app credentials in the backend token server to generate an access token, I encountered a 403 Forbidden error when loading the models. This error occurs even though the models are visible on the Autodesk Build website from the CEO's ACC account.
I initially used my APS web app credentials to generate the access token, and the models loaded without issues.
However, when I switched to using the company CEO's APS app credentials, I expected the models to load similarly, but instead, I received a 403 Forbidden error. I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully load models using the company CEO's APS web app credentials.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
